# RESTful Multiple Updates (Example: Clear a Shopping Cart)?

Tags: rest, shopping-cart

Let's say I have I have an online store with a "shopping cart" feature and I want to implement an "empty cart" link in a RESTful way.

For simplicity, let's say my resources are a Cart that contains CartItems, each of which has a Product. My URIs might be:

```
# add a product to the current user's Cart
POST /products/product_id/cart_items/

# remove a product from the current user's Cart
DELETE /cart_items/cart_item_id/
```

If so, what would the RESTful URI for the "empty cart" link look like?

Instead, I could think of the Cart as a general-purpose holder for Actions ([as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411462/restful-way-to-create-multiple-items-in-one-request)):

```
# add a product
# form data contains e.g., product_id=123&action=add
POST /carts/cart_id/actions/

# remove a product
# action_id is the id of the action adding product 123
DELETE actions/action_id

# empty cart
# form data contains action=clear
POST /carts/cart_id/actions/
```

This approach seems more complicated than it needs to be. What would be a better way?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Don't do the second approach. Funneling different `actions` through one endpoint does not feel RESTful IMO.

You have `DELETE /cart_items/cart_item_id/` that removes `cart_item_id` from their cart. What about `DELETE /cart_items/` to clear the cart itself?

Answer (score 8):

Adding an item to a cart:

`POST carts/{cartid}/items`

Retrieving a specific item from the cart:

`GET carts/{cartid}/items/{itemid}`

Deleting a specific item from the cart:

`DELETE carts/{cartid}/items/{itemid}`

Getting the state of the cart:

`GET carts/{cartid}/state`

(Could return a value like 0,1 that indicates the number of items in the cart)

Emptying the cart:

`PUT carts/{cartid}/state?state=0`

Does this look intuitive?

Comment: Emptying the cart with `DELETE carts/{cartid}/items` looks much more intuitive in your (otherwise very clear) example.

Comment: Any security concerns about putting a cartId in a URL?

Comment: @Breako not if the cartid is a randomly generated guid. Even then security checks should be done to validate the "owner" of the cart.

Answer (score 1):

`DELETE /cart_items/` is an interesting idea that has [also been discussed here](http://dev.rubyonrails.org/ticket/11022).