# RESTful using Jersey: method to POST multiple entities

Tags: rest, multiple-entries

I am trying to develop a method in my RESTful web service in Java to insert multiple entries into a MySQL DB using POST request. The generated RESTful Web Service has a method to insert a single entity, but not multiple ones. For example, it accepts:

```
<creature>
  <sort>Mouse</sort> 
  <name>Pinky</name>
</creature>
```

But not (what I would like):

```
<creature>
  <sort>Mouse</sort> 
  <name>Pinky</name>
</creature>
<creature>
  <sort>Elephant</sort> 
  <name>Dumbo</name>
</creature>
```

I'm guessing that you have to loop through the entities, but not sure how to implement it, being a shameful novice.

Answer (score 5):

Just ran into this myself.  I need transactional posts of multiple items, so iterating on the client is out of the question.  The consensus seems to be that you need to use a separate path from your normal resources:

http://chasenlehara.com/blog/creating-restful-web-services/ (Multi-resources)

[RESTful way to create multiple items in one request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411462/restful-way-to-create-multiple-items-in-one-request)

I couldn't find much about how to do this with Jersey, though.  As it turns out, it's pretty easy.  You should already have multi-entity converter and resource classes for GET requests, you just need to specify a path where the server can assume it's going to receive them:

```
@Path("creatures")
@Stateless
public class CreaturesResource {

...

    @POST
    @Consumes({"application/xml", "application/json"})
    public Response post(CreatureConverter data) {
       Creature entity = data.resolveEntity(em);
        postCreature(entity);
    }

    @POST @Path("multi")
    @Consumes({"application/xml", "application/json"})
    public Response postMulti(CreaturesConverter data) {
       Collection<Creature> entities = data.getEntities();
       for (Creature c : entities) {
            postCreature(c);
       }
    }
```

Then instead of posting

```
<creature />
```

to

```
http://.../resources/creatures
```

You would post

```
<creatures>
    <creature />
    <creature />
</creatures>
```

to

```
http://.../resources/creatures/multi
```