# extend Backbone.sync to batch sync?

Tags: backbone.js

What technique shall one use to implement batch insert/update for Backbone.sync?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess it depends on your usage scenarios, and how much you want to change the calling code. I think you have two options:

**Option 1: No Change to client (calling) code**

Oddly enough the annotated [source for Backbone.sync](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-164) gives 'batching' as a possible reason for overriding the `sync` method:

> Use setTimeout to batch rapid-fire updates into a single request.

Instead of actually saving on sync, add the request to a queue, and only batch-save every so often. [`_.throttle`](http://underscorejs.org/#throttle) or [`_.delay`](http://underscorejs.org/#delay) might help you here.

**Option 2: Change client code**

Alternatively, instead of calling `save` on your models, you could add some sort of `save` method to collections. You'd have to track which models were actually modified and hence in need of update, since as far as I can tell, Backbone only knows whether they're new or not (but I could be wrong about that).

Comment: If I use `_.throttle` or `_.delay`, how do I send multiple 'updates' in a single ajax request?  array of models?

Comment: There's various ways, and really it depends on your patterns of data access. There's a discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/411462/restful-way-to-create-multiple-items-in-one-request

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I did it

```
Backbone.originalSync = Backbone.sync;

Backbone.sync = function (method, model, options) {
    //
    // code to extend sync
    //

    // calling original sync 
    Backbone.originalSync(method, model, options);
}
```

works fine for me , and I use it to control every ajax request coming out of any model or collection