# A call between REST principles and Performance

Tags: performance, rest, http

Can i send multiple objects in POST and PUT http endpoints. I have 50 objects which i need to insert or update in database. The recommendation from the technical fellow group here is to make 50 calls and insert/update individual elements. In this case how does my Front-end application perform?.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RESTful way to create multiple items in one request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/411462/restful-way-to-create-multiple-items-in-one-request)

Comment: Your goal is to be more performant ? or you  really want to send multiple objects in one call ?

Comment: My goal is to be more performant but without suppressing the REST principles

Answer (score 0):

Your technical fellow group IMHO is wrong, rest is not about sending one or many objects, from your description your application could be a classical [RPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call) application, that sends objects and receives objects (encoded as json) and that someone called REST because uses HTTP. Rest is more about being [stateless](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Stateless)  and links ([HATEOAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS)) presented to the client in the response.

So send as much objects as you want, if you can.

Can you ? Just wondering if the actual problem is that there is no URL to send many objects to so they told you send one by one ;-)