# How to create a document that includes an array of ObjectIds of another collection (best-practice, RESTful)?

Tags: mongodb, rest, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Using `Mongoose` and a `RESTful API` I'd like to have 2 collections (`organizations` and `projects`), whereas the `Schema` of the former should hold a field `projects`of type `[ObjectId]`, which references documents of the latter - and vice versa.
Creating a new organization (POST /organizations) one could either (a) leave the `projects` field blank and add project documents later (POST /projects) or (b) create some projects with it already.

The problems for (b):

1. It seems to be in conflict with RESTfulness, because posting a
   new organization should have a different API point than posting a
   new project - but we want to achieve both in one go.
2. When we create a new organization the field `projects` should hold an array
   of ObjectIds referring to the corresponding projects - but these
   won't have IDs yet.

There are probably many ways to accomplish the goal - i.e. 2 successive POST requests: Projects first, then the organization.
But I'd like to learn about best-practice for this szenario.

Oranization Schema:

```
{
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    address: { type: String },
    // projects = array of ObjectIds referring to Project documents
    projects: { type: [Mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId] }
}
```

Project Schema:

```
{
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    start: { type: Date },
    end: { type: Date },
    organization: { type: Mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId }
}
```

Provided problem description and code are simplified examples for a bigger project that will have many models/collections with a lot of cross-referencing.

One could have projects as an array of sub-documents of an organization document, but I'd prefer to have the projects as an independent collection, since it should be possible to request the whole collection for a projects view, without having to crawl through the organizations documents.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I found some good ideas in another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411462/restful-way-to-create-multiple-items-in-one-request/25876752) (which is about posting multiple items of the same resource type - as opposed to posting one item which includes another item of a different resource type):

@RESTfulness:

> resources don't need to map to your database or app models

So, basically I could treat "Organization" as a resource which can include a project and do a POST request `/organizations`, and server-side I create a new document for the projects collection, then a new document for the organizations collection (where the ObjectId of the project doc is being pushed to the field `projects`).

The problem with this would be the response, when something goes wrong with updating the DB: The response should hold information of which document creation failed.

Alternatively one could send a POST request `/organizations` as soon as name and address are filled out in the form. This will result in adding an organization to the organizations collection of the DB. Then, in case a project is added inside the same form, we do another POST request `/projects` passing the newly created organization id with it. Server-side we create a new project document, then push its id to the projects array of the organization document.